# Angular - List with different components

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to make a wall, and I have 3 different wall post types.

- Text
- Photos
- Video

What's the best practice? 3 different components, or 1 component with 3 cases inside?

How can I select the right component inside my *ngFor ?

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
   <text-post *ngIf="post.type == 1"></text-post>
   <photo-post *ngIf="post.type == 2"></photo-post>
   <video-post *ngIf="post.type == 3"></video-post>
</div>
```

Comment: One component and 3 cases is a solid way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for one component with a `ngSwitch` in it.

So you could do something like this for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="post.type">
        <text-post *ngSwitchCase="1"></text-post>
        <photo-post *ngSwitchCase="2"></photo-post>
        <video-post *ngSwitchCase="3"></video-post>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

`ng-container` is an element that does not get rendered in the DOM and therefore does not interfere with the layout of the page.